# Split line with distance and particular point

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

I try to split line, or exactly, I want to make a new line between 2 lines.
I try to interpolate point, but it's create 1 point on every node. I need only on start point.
I try to buffer point, but it's make 2 points, only need 1.
I try to translate, but how to follow line ?
It's complex, I need : 2 different points, split line under the new point and add id from point to line...

I use QGIS 3.16.

[image]

Comment: How do you choose which direction from which vertice you want to place the new point, as well as which distance?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do

Comment: Direction have no importance. distance can be set arbitrarily (50cm i.e.). I need "just" a new vertice between 2 vertices,  respecting topology.